# Select last N rows with multiple values in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have a table:

messages:

< id - title - body - city - street - building - created on >

While I was able to select required messages in multiple queries, I need to do it in a single one:

Here are my queries at the moment:

```
$queryOne = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `body`, `created_on` FROM `fcm_messages` WHERE `city`='$city' AND `street`='$street' AND `building`='$building'";
$queryTwo = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `body`, `created_on` FROM `fcm_messages` WHERE `city`='$city' AND `street`='$street' AND `building`='-'";
$queryThree = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `body`, `created_on` FROM `fcm_messages` WHERE `city`='$city' AND `street`='-' AND `building`='-'";
$queryFour = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `body`, `created_on` FROM `fcm_messages` WHERE `city`='-' AND `street`='-' AND `building`='-'";
```

I need one query because I can then use ORDER BY id DESC which will sort all the messages perfectly suitable for my needs.

I could apply same sorting to the queries I have right now, but it would give same result because later on they're pushed into array one after another and the order would be messed up.

Comment: So join your existing WHERE clauses from all the queries with OR …?

Comment: @CBroe Meaning that I should just do $queryOne or $queryTwo or $queryThree or $queryFour?

Comment: No, of course not, that does not even make sense. Make _one_ query, that uses `WHERE (…) OR (…) OR …`

Comment: Note that there is a convention for storing unknown values as NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simpler approach is boolean logic:

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `body`, `created_on` 
FROM `fcm_messages` 
WHERE 
    (`city` = :city AND `street` = :street AND `building` = :building)
    OR (`city` = :city AND `street` = :street AND `building` = '-')
    OR (`city` = :city AND `street` = '-' AND `building` = '-')
    OR (`city` = '-' AND `street` = '-' AND `building` = '-')
```

Note that this uses query parameters to pass the variables to the query rather than concatenating them into the query string: this is both safer and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a query simply by putting each condition into brackets and combine them by a logical OR for each one.

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `body`, `created_on` FROM `fcm_messages` WHERE ";

$conditions[] = "(`city`='$city' AND `street`='$street' AND `building`='$building')";
$conditions[] = "(`city`='$city' AND `street`='$street' AND `building`='-')";
$conditions[] = "(`city`='$city' AND `street`='-' AND `building`='-')";
$conditions[] = "(`city`='-' AND `street`='-' AND `building`='-')";

$query .= join(' OR ', $conditions);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can take advantage of tuples:

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `body`, `created_on` 
FROM `fcm_messages` 
WHERE (city, street, building) in ( (:city, :street, :building), (:city, :street, '-'), (:city, '-', '-'), ('-', '-', '-') )
```

Note:  In many cases, the "generic" value would be stored as `NULL`.  That would not work with `IN`, but with `'-'` it does.